# Trimble Geo 7x Data Transfer from Pathfinder Office

Tags: trimble, pathfinder

I have developed a data dictionary which i want to transfer to my company's newly acquired Geo 7X but GPS pathfinder office is having trouble connecting to the device even though i can see it in Window Mobile Center

Comment: Are you using Data transfer module from Pathfinder? Sometimes you need to create and set a new device to connect it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Using Terrasync? If you're positive your DDF file is OK and you're just having trouble with PFO seeing your GPS, you can use Windows file explorer to try to copy/paste it to the "...My Documents\TerraSync" folder on your GPS where all your data files get saved and should appear as a selectable data dictionary on the New  Data File screen.